# Windows Case-Sensitivity

Tags: windows, directory, operating-system, filesystems

I have been web developing on a windows machine and run into an issue that took me quite a while to figure out. The issue was caused by the case insensitivity of the windows system. The issue was created because multiple version of react were being used and causing issues with the react dom. Is there any reason that folders and directories are not case sensitive? Is there a way to globally enforce case sensitivity for all directories on windows?

Comment: There's an "obcaseinsensitive" flag that forces NT object opens to use the flag [`OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ntdef/ns-ntdef-_object_attributes) if the object type is unknown or if the object type is flagged as case insensitive.

Comment: Normally the Windows file API uses `OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE` anyway, but it omits it in a couple of cases: `CreateFileW` w/ `FILE_FLAG_POSIX_SEMANTICS` and `FindFirstFileExW` w/ `FIND_FIRST_EX_CASE_SENSITIVE`. Those file API flags will actually work as advertised if the system "obcaseinsensitive" flag is false, but changing it requires a reboot, so this isn't really a viable alternative in most cases.

Comment: In Windows 10, NTFS supports forced case-sensitive directories, of which the contents are always compared case sensitive regardless of whether an open specifies the `OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE` flag, either explicitly or implicitly (via the "obcaseinsensitive" system flag). You can set this flag on a directory with `fsutil file setCaseSensitiveInfo`.